# form_dropdown() in Codeigniter form return wrong value

Tags: php

I'm updating some controlles from Tank_auth, and I'm trying to insert a dropdown in the register_form. The dropdown contains an array from a sql query. 
Model Code:

```
public function get_group(){

  $query = $this->DB1->query('SELECT val7 from table group by val7;');
  if($query->num_rows()>0){
    $group= array();
    foreach($query->result_array() as $r){
       $group[$r['val7']] = $r['val7'];
    }
  }

  return $group;
```

}

And the view code:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <?php echo form_label('Grupo', $grupo['id'], array('class' => 'control-label')); ?>
    <div class="controls">
        <?php echo form_error('grupo'); ?>                               
        <?php echo form_dropdown('grupo',$list_groups)?>
        <p class="help-block"></p>
    </div>
```

The array shows: Array ( [cliente1] => cliente1 [cliente2] => cliente2 [cliente3] => cliente3 )  then to submit the form it writes to a DB but it writes a 0 value.
In the controller I use:

```
$this->form_validation->set_value('grupo')
```

What's the best way?

Thanks a lot.

**EDIT**
More information about the php code:
The view file:

```
    <!--Top of file, more code-->
    $grupo = array(
    'name'  => 'grupo',
    'id'    => 'grupo',
    'value' => set_value('grupo'),
    );
    <!--rest of the form, start the form_dropdown()-->
    <div class="control-group">
    <?php echo form_label('Grupo', $grupo['id'], array('class' => 'control-label')); ?>
    <div class="controls">
        <?php echo form_error('grupo'); ?>                               
        <?php echo form_dropdown('grupo',$list_groups)?>
        <p class="help-block"></p>
    </div>
    <!--rest of the form, end of view-->
```

controller:

```
     <!--top of the controller and resto of the code, start validation-->    
     $this->form_validation->set_rules('grupo', 'Grupo', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
     <!--rest of all validations, pass the values to $data array and create_user    function-->    
     $this->form_validation->set_value('grupo'),
```

The library:

```
     <!--start function with arguments-->    
     function create_user($username, $email, $password, $email_activation, $grupo){
     $data = array(
    'username'  => $username,
    'password'  => $hashed_password,
    'email'     => $email,
    'servicegroup'  => $grupo,
    'last_ip'   => $this->ci->input->ip_address(),
    );
```

The model:

```
if ($this->db->insert($this->table_name, $data)) {
        $user_id = $this->db->insert_id();
        if ($activated) $this->create_profile($user_id);
        return array('user_id' => $user_id);
    }
```

The result is an empty variable for servicegroup.
I think this is problem of the form_dropdwon not passing the values to the controller.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: when the form is generated in the browser, does it render with the correct values or are all the values set to 0?

Comment: It render with correct values, it shows a dropdown with the 3 values: cliente1, cliente2, cliente 3. I try to write the array manually but it still insert a 0 to the DB field. Thanks!

Comment: if its all being rendered correctly, 0 can be entered in through various different things. 2 common problems, if your casting (bool) or (int) against the value, or the value is not being correctly passed to the db method. can you show the controller and model code because that is where this issue will be and will help someone else debug it for you?

Comment: Edited the post with more information about the code. Thanks mic :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!!
just a simple problem with the argument order.